# Android Translucent status bar differs in different devices

Tags: android, material-design, status

`Translucent` Status bar differs in **different devices**.

For example, in Note 4, the `translucent` part looks like **shadow**.

In Note 3 , the `translucent` part is **not showing**. In most of the other devices it's there!

I have used , `windowTranslucentStatus = true` in my app's theme. Any idea to solve this?

[Find the Note 4 Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcV35.png)

Comment: what are their Android versions respectively?

Comment: All are run on Lollipop

Answer (score 1):

Translucent status bar looks like shadow on all Android KitKat devices. Samsung Lollipop devices don't show a status bar at all. Other Lollipop devices show a translucent black rectangle.

I was struggling with that and seems like there's no good solution. You can:

- Assume that it just works and don't care about differences.
- Use translucent status only on Lollipop and M (KitKat stays with black opaque status bar).
- Use opaque status bar with color set to colorPrimaryDark (this solution is pretty good, but doesn't work if you wish to have a drawer or a header with an image drawn over the status bar.
- Check if the device you're using is a 'samsung' or anything else and pick status bar's settings accordingly.